# Iterating through a string and compare it with another to check if the characters in the first are into the second

Tags: c++, string

how can i do it?
the whole day i've been looking everywhere for a solution :(
it' in c++ and all the question is in the title, thank you

```
if(fp.is_open())
{
    while(getline(fp, buff))
    {
        if(buff.length() == lung)
        {
            // check if the characters are in the string

            while(found != string::npos)
            {
                cout << i << "\r";

                for(int x = 0; x < buff.length(); ++x)
                {
                    found = lettere_possibili.find(buff[x]);

                    if(found == string::npos)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                ++i;        
            }

            j = 0;
        }

        ++k;
    }

    fp.close();
}
```

Comment: You just wanna compare two string to show if they're exactly the same??

Comment: Are you looking if one string is a *substring* of the second one? Is it significant which one is a substring of which? (i.e. is input `("aa","aaa")` will yield the same answer as `("aaa","aa")`)

Comment: So you're checking if one is an anagram of another? I'd just sort them and check for equality.

Comment: Whoa. The logic in your code is maybe five lines long (actually much shorter), and yet your code is almost too long to fit on my screen. Vertical waste also leads to unreadable code!

Comment: i'm trying to create a program that solves a game i have on the iphone (Draw)

Comment: it gives you an image and n letters, i want to create a program that get that letters in input and search a word list to the possible solution

Answer (score 5):

The question is not exactly clear, but it seems to me as if you're looking for `find_first_not_of()`:

```
bool containsOnlyCharsFromPossibili = (buff.find_first_not_of(lettere_possibili) == string::npos);
```

Comment: thank you sooooo much, i've been struggling from this morning to solve the problem, i love you <3

Comment: @DomenicoMastrangelo If the answer solved the problem for you, how about accepting it?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

void find_chars(const std::string &first, const std::string &second)
{
    std::string::const_iterator s;

    for (s = second.begin(); s != second.end(); ++s)
    {
        if (first.find(*s) != std::string::npos)
        {
            std::cout << *s << " is in " << second << "\n";
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    find_chars("abc", "abcdef");
}
```

Here's the output:

```
a is in abcdef
b is in abcdef
c is in abcdef
```

Comment: i've done that but i cannot get the program to iterate through a word and if that contains all the characters you're searching for and it's exactly long how you want it to be, show it on command line and only than go to the next word

Comment: if it doesn't have all the characters in it, and if the characters in the first string are not in second

for ex:

pappagalloverk
pappagallini

i and n are not in "pappagalloverk" and so it should just go to the next one